# Code is working on CodePen but on my pc there are a lot of mistakes with JS file (maybe because of ES6)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

Here is the result what i want to have: `https://codepen.io/sldkfjwelkgmerbgki/pen/RwQBrWJ`

I tried to export theese files and open it in browser. But when i open a html file there was a mistake: *Cannot use import statement outside a module*

Then i changed the name of sctipt file from js to mjs and said that the type of this file should be "module".
When i tried to open it one more time i have such mistake:
*Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/.../script.mjs' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*

Then i opened it on my hosting `http://2178559.rp411870.web.hosting-test.net/sites/try/` (site on WP). And now it has this mistake:
*Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.*

**Please help me export and use this code from CodePen properly, without mistakes. Try to use this code, i don't understand how this code working on other sites also `https://jsfiddle.net/dn6pwre4/4/`, but when i try to use it on my PC from file nothing happens**

Answer (score 0):

Set `type="module"` on your `<script>` tag in order to use import statements. Keep the file extension as `.js`.

Comment: Why it's not working, when i ran the website as a file? (index.html)?

Comment: And can i open it as a file, what should i do?